# Passing a LPCTSTR parameter to an API call from VBA in a PTRSAFE and UNICODE safe manner

Tags: ms-access, vba, pointers, dll

I've been fighting with this for a good week.   I am having difficulties when passing string pointers to a DLL function.

#### Background

We have just started migrating to Office 2010, from Office 2003.   Some people will continue to only have Office 2003 for the next few years.  Some people will be using Office 2010 64-bit (why I don't know - but that's a different subject).

For me - I need to make some code that will work on all versions.   I had found this function on the internet some years back and was using it.   When I went to do a rewrite on my library, I noticed that there was a total mixture of Unicode vs ANSI calls ..  and the function outright did not work on Access 2010.  So I went to re-write it.   I think I'm close - but I notice that the dll calls are not returning the proper values.

#### What I've done to attempt to solve the problem

- I have made sure I read up on ByRef and ByVal parameter passing.
- I've read up on the difference between varptr() and strptr().  I believe I am using them correctly.
- I've tried declaring the [lpctstr](/questions/tagged/lpctstr) as a string but am uncomfortable with this approach since I am unsure how it will play out on a 64-Bit system, or on a Unicode system.

  - When working with pointers - such oversights will crash and potentially corrupt a DB
  - Using pointers means I don't have to convert to and from Unicode - its either in Unicode or it isn't - and the conditional compilation statements ensure the proper functions are referenced.

#### Short Summary Example

```
Public Sub foo()
   Dim strA As String
   Dim strCB As String
#If VB7 Then
   Dim lptstrA As LongPtr
   Dim lResult As LongPtr
#Else
   Dim lptstrA As Long
   Dim lResult As Long
#End If  
   
   strA = "T:\TEST\"
   lptstrA = StrPtr(strA)
   strCB = String$(255, vbNullChar)

   lResult = PathIsNetworkPath(lptstrA)
#If UNICODE Then
   CopyMemory StrPtr(strCB), lptstrA, (Len(strA))
#Else
   CopyMemory StrPtr(strCB), lptstrA, (Len(strA) * 2)
#End If
   Debug.Print "Returned: " & lResult
   Debug.Print "Buffer: " & strCB
   Debug.Print "Result: " & strA
End Sub
```

This, in my mind should work.   I'm passing the pointer to the string.  But...

*Results*

> > foo
> >     Returned: 0
> >     Buffer:   T:\TEST\
> >     Result: T:\TEST\

So the function is returning zero ..  it should return 1.   But if we examine the contents of the memory at the pointer - it clearly has the data in it.

## Full Code

#### (Doesn't Work)

```
Option Explicit
'
' WNetGetConnection Return Result Constants
Private Const ERROR_SUCCESS As Long = 0&
Private Const ERROR_BAD_DEVICE As Long = 1200&
Private Const ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED = 2250&
Private Const ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234&
Private Const ERROR_CONNECTION_UNAVAIL = 1201&
Private Const ERROR_NO_NETWORK = 1222&
Private Const ERROR_EXTENDED_ERROR = 1208&
Private Const ERROR_NO_NET_OR_BAD_PATH = 1203&
'
' WNetGetConnection function retrieves the name of the network resource
' associated with a local device.
'   > msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385453(v=vs.85).aspx
'   - If the function succeeds, the return value is NO_ERROR.
'   - If the function fails, the return value is a system error code, such as
'     one of the following values.
'
' PathIsUNC function determines if the string is a valid Universal Naming
' Convention (UNC) for a server and share path.
'   > msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773712(v=vs.85).aspx
'   - Returns TRUE if the string is a valid UNC path, or FALSE otherwise.
'
' PathIsNetworkPath function determines whether a path string represents a
' network resource.
'   > msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773640(v=vs.85).aspx
'   - Returns TRUE if the string represents a network resource, or FALSE
'     otherwise.
'
' PathStripToRoot function removes all parts of the path except for the root
' information.
'   > msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773757(v=vs.85).aspx
'   - Returns TRUE if a valid drive letter was found in the path, or FALSE
'     otherwise.
'
' PathSkipRoot function parses a path, ignoring the drive letter or Universal
' Naming Convention (UNC) server/share path elements.
'   > msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773754(v=vs.85).aspx
'   - Returns the address of the beginning of the subpath that follows the root
'     (drive letter or UNC server/share).
'
' PathRemoveBackslash function removes the trailing backslash from a given
' path.
'   > msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773743(v=vs.85).aspx
'   - Returns the address of the NULL that replaced the backslash, or the
'     address of the last character if it's not a backslash.


' For Access 2010 64-Bit Support, as well as backward compatibility
#If VBA7 Then

  #If UNICODE Then

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function WNetGetConnection _
                   Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetGetConnectionW" ( _
                                  ByVal lpLocalName As LongPtr, _
                                  ByVal lpRemoteName As LongPtr, _
                                  lpnLength As Long _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function PathIsUNC _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathIsUNCW" ( _
                                  ByVal pszPath As LongPtr _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function PathIsNetworkPath _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathIsNetworkPathW" ( _
                                  ByVal pszPath As LongPtr _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function PathStripToRoot _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathStripToRootW" ( _
                                  ByVal pPath As LongPtr _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function PathSkipRoot _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathSkipRootW" ( _
                                  ByVal pPath As LongPtr _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function PathRemoveBackslash _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathRemoveBackslashW" ( _
                                  ByVal strPath As LongPtr _
                                 ) As LongPtr

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function lStrLen _
                   Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrlenW" ( _
                                  ByVal lpString as longptr _
                                 ) As Integer
  #Else

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function WNetGetConnection _
                   Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetGetConnectionA" ( _
                                  ByVal lpLocalName As LongPtr, _
                                  ByVal lpRemoteName As LongPtr, _
                                  ByVal lpnLength As Long _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function PathIsUNC _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathIsUNCA" ( _
                                  ByVal pszPath As LongPtr _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function PathIsNetworkPath _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathIsNetworkPathA" ( _
                                  ByVal pszPath As LongPtr _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function PathStripToRoot _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathStripToRootA" ( _
                                  ByVal pPath As LongPtr _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function PathSkipRoot _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathSkipRootA" ( _
                                  ByVal pPath As LongPtr _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function PathRemoveBackslash _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathRemoveBackslashA" ( _
                                  ByVal strPath As LongPtr _
                                 ) As LongPtr

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function lStrLen _
                   Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrlenA" ( _
                                  ByVal lpString As LongPtr _
                                 ) As Integer

  #End If

  Public Declare Sub CopyMemory _
                 Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" ( _
                                ByVal Destination As LongPtr, _
                                ByVal Source As LongPtr, _
                                ByVal Length As Long _
                               )

#Else

  #If UNICODE Then

    Public Declare Function WNetGetConnection _
                   Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetGetConnectionW" ( _
                                  ByVal lpLocalName As Long, _
                                  ByVal lpRemoteName As Long, _
                                  lpnLength As Long _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare Function PathIsUNC _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathIsUNCW" ( _
                                  ByVal pszPath As Long _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare Function PathIsNetworkPath _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathIsNetworkPathW" ( _
                                  ByVal pszPath As Long _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare Function PathStripToRoot _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathStripToRootW" ( _
                                  ByVal pPath As Long _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare Function PathSkipRoot _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathSkipRootW" ( _
                                  ByVal pPath As Long _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare Function PathRemoveBackslash _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathRemoveBackslashW" ( _
                                  ByVal strPath As Long _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare Function lStrLen _
                   Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrlenW" ( _
                                  ByVal lpString As Long _
                                 ) As Integer
 #Else

    Public Declare Function WNetGetConnection _
                   Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetGetConnectionA" ( _
                                  ByVal lpLocalName As Long, _
                                  ByVal lpRemoteName As Long, _
                                  ByVal lpnLength As Long _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare Function PathIsUNC _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathIsUNCA" ( _
                                  ByVal pszPath As Long _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare Function PathIsNetworkPath _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathIsNetworkPathA" ( _
                                  ByVal pszPath As Long _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare Function PathStripToRoot _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathStripToRootA" ( _
                                  ByVal pPath As Long _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare Function PathSkipRoot _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathSkipRootA" ( _
                                  ByVal pPath As Long _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare Function PathRemoveBackslash _
                   Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathRemoveBackslashA" ( _
                                  ByVal strPath As Long _
                                 ) As Long

    Public Declare Function lStrLen _
                   Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrlenA" ( _
                                  ByVal lpString As Long _
                                 ) As Integer

  #End If

  Public Declare Sub CopyMemory _
                   Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" ( _
                                  ByVal Destination As Long, _
                                  ByVal Source As Long, _
                                  ByVal Length As Long _
                                 )

#End If

Public Function GetUncPath(tsLocal As String) As String  
   Dim tsRoot As String  
   Dim tsPath As String  
   Dim tsRemoteRoot As String  
   Dim tsRemote As String  
   Dim tcbTemp As String  
   #If VBA7 Then  
     Dim lptsLocal As LongPtr  
     Dim lptsRoot As LongPtr  
     Dim lptsPath As LongPtr  
     Dim lptsRemote As LongPtr  
     Dim lptcbTemp As LongPtr  
     Dim lpResult As LongPtr  
   #Else  
     Dim lptsLocal As Long  
     Dim lptsRoot As Long  
     Dim lptsPath As Long  
     Dim lptsRemote As Long  
     Dim lptcbTemp As Long  
     Dim lpResult As Long  
   #End If  
   Dim lResult As Long  

   ' Initialize strings.   Since Strings are essentially a pointer to  
   ' a pointer, we use StrPtr() instead of VarPtr()  
   '  
   tsLocal = tsLocal & vbNullChar       ' Just in case  
   tsRoot = String(255, vbNullChar)     ' Path Root / Drive Letter  
   tsPath = String(255, vbNullChar)     ' Path Without Root  
   tsRemote = String(255, vbNullChar)   ' Remote Path + Root, Resolved  
   tcbTemp = String(255, vbNullChar)    ' Temporary Copy Buffer  
   lptsLocal = StrPtr(tsLocal)          ' Pointer to Local Path  
   lptsRoot = StrPtr(tsRoot)            ' Pointer to Root  
   lptsPath = StrPtr(tsPath)            ' Pointer to Path  
   lptsRemote = StrPtr(tsRemote)        ' Pointer to Remote  

   ' Check is already in UNC Format  
   lResult = PathIsUNC(lptsLocal)  
   If (lResult <> 0) Then  
     GetUncPath = tsLocal
     Exit Function
   End If

   ' Check if its a local path or network.  If Local - use that path.
   lResult = PathIsNetworkPath(lptsLocal)  
>! PathIsNetworkPath(lptsLocal) always returns 0
   If lResult = 0 Then
     GetUncPath = tsLocal
     Exit Function
   End If

   ' Extract our root from path (ie. Drive letter)
   ' ### lStrLen(lptsLocal returns 1 ??  ###
   CopyMemory lptsRoot, lptsLocal, lStrLen(lptsLocal) 
>! lStrLen(lptsLocal) always returns 1 -- unsure why
   lResult = PathStripToRoot(lptsRoot)
   If (lResult = 0) Then
     ' An error has occurred
     GetUncPath = ""
     Exit Function
    End If

   ' Strip Backslash
   lpResult = PathRemoveBackslash(lptsRoot)

   ' Find our Path portion
   CopyMemory lptsPath, lptsLocal, lStrLen(lptsLocal)
   lptsPath = PathSkipRoot(lptsPath)

   ' Strip Backslash
   lpResult = PathRemoveBackslash(lptsPath)

   ' Convert our Root to a UNC Network format
   lResult = WNetGetConnection(lptsRemote, lptsRoot, lStrLen(lptsRoot))
   If lResult = ERROR_SUCCESS Then
     tsRemote = tsRemote & tsPath     ' Add Remote + Path to build UNC path
     GetUncPath = tsRemote            ' Return resolved path
   Else
     ' Errors have occurred
     GetUncPath = ""
   End If
End Function
```

What am I missing?

Comment: + 1 for taking the time out to explain the problem and for showing what you have tried :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you have done is a little abstraction to pretend strings are always pointers (hmm... actually, that's a reverse abstraction to remove the built-in abstraction that pointers are strings).

You now need an easy way to use that abstraction.

Have a class, `WrappedString` (*not tested, don't have Office 2010*):

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

Private buf() As Byte

Friend Sub Init(s As String)
  Dim len_of_s_in_bytes As Long
  len_of_s_in_bytes = LenB(s)

  If len_of_s_in_bytes = 0 Then Exit Sub

  #If UNICODE Then
    ReDim b(1 To len_of_s_in_bytes + 2) 'Adding the null terminator
    CopyMemory b(LBound(b)), ByVal StrPtr(s), len_of_s_in_bytes
  #Else
    b = StrConv(s & vbNullChar, vbFromUnicode)
  #End If

End Sub

#If VB7 Then
Public Property Get Pointer() As LongPtr
  Pointer = VarPtr(b(LBound(b)))
End Property
#Else
Public Property Get Pointer() As Long
  Pointer = VarPtr(b(LBound(b)))
End Property
#End If
```

*Why you need a class and not just a conversion function: to avoid memory leaks. An allocated pointer needs to be freed, the class destructor will take care of that.*

Then have a construction function in a module:

```
Public Function ToWrappedString(s As String) As WrappedString
  Set ToWrappedString = New WrappedString
  ToWrappedString.Init s
End Function
```

Then you can call your functions:

```
lResult = PathIsNetworkPath(ToWrappedString("T:\TEST\").Pointer)
```

---

Obviously, you can take this abstraction one little step further:

Have a module, put all your `declare`s there and make them private.
Then have public functions in that module, one for each `declare`d function (that is, `Public Function PathSkipRoot (...) As String`, `Public Function PathRemoveBackslash (...) As String` etc, and make each of those public wrappers to call the `declare`d functions using `WrappedString`.
Then the rest of the code will only see plain `String` versions of the functions.

Comment: Your example is concise .. but maybe I've been chasing my tail so long I've forgotten where I was going. Perhaps the question I should be asking is, "Do I *NEED* to reverse abstract - or am I over-engineering this?" Maybe Access 2010 handles the string -> LongPtr abstraction already (with and without UNICODE) and I don't need to concern myself with it.

Comment: @DHW If you are saying you *must* use Unicode versions of functions where they are supported, then yes, you have to use some sort of abstraction, because VB will autoconvert a string to ansi when calling a `declared` function, on both unicode and non-unicode systems. But then, your software may behave differently on different machines, (like, you enter a path in Chinese, it succeeds on one PC and fails on another). If you would rather prefer it fail on both PCs, then just remove the `UNICODE` check and only use `A` versions of declared functions, which means `As String` for all parameters.

Comment: @DHW Alternatively, you may observe the fact that the [oldest OS supported by Office 2003 is Windows 2000 SP3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822129), and that one is Unicode. Therefore, all your systems are Unicode, and you can omit the non-Unicode block of declares, and always use `PathIsNetworkPath(StrPtr("T:\TEST\"))`.

Comment: I wondered about that. I would think a new computer running XP SP3 would be unicode. However, when I try the following code, it says I am Non-Unicode: #If UNICODE Then Debug.Print "UC" #Else Debug.Print "Not UC" #End If

Comment: @DHW But this is not a predefined constant. I thought you had a way of setting it to something; if you don't, then it's False by default.

Comment: I converted the code to get rid of the abstraction. I now recall why I started down that road in the first place. `strA = "T:\FOO\": PathStripToRoot strA` will modify strA, placing a null character at the location of where the root ends and the path begins. Normally you could pull out the string by simply using `mid()` in conjunction with `instr(strA,vbnullchar)` however the `instr()` when used on a UNICODE string will stop on the second byte of the 2-byte unicode character... and I can't find an `instr()` equivilent that works with both ANSI and UNICODE

Comment: In the end, considering the memory leak issue - I think your solution is best. I've marked it as the answer. I'm going to write an APIString class that has `.Value` properties (Get/Let) as well as `TruncFromPointer` and `TruncToPointer` methods. I'll post the completed code (as an answer) on this thread so other people can see the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the final product I came up with - feel free to suggest critiques.

As it was pointed out by Gserg, I don't need to worry about whether strings are stored as single-byte characters within memory, since every modern computer will now be using Unicode.   Due to this, I was able to eliminate use of the CopyMemory function and use pointer arithmetic instead.

I opted out from using an object factory wrapper and instead controlled the class initilization myself.

This has been tested on Access 2003 and Access 2010.  It is 32-bit and 64-bit compatible.

**Module: GetUNC**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function WNetGetConnection Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetGetConnectionW" (ByVal lpLocalName As LongPtr, ByVal lpRemoteName As Long, lpnLength As Long) As Long
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function PathIsUNC Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathIsUNCW" (ByVal pszPath As LongPtr) As Long
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function PathIsNetworkPath Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathIsNetworkPathW" (ByVal pszPath As LongPtr) As Long
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function PathStripToRoot Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathStripToRootW" (ByVal pPath As LongPtr) As LongPtr
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function PathSkipRoot Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathSkipRootW" (ByVal pPath As LongPtr) As Long
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function PathRemoveBackslash Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathRemoveBackslashW" (ByVal strPath As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
  Private Declare Function WNetGetConnection Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetGetConnectionW" (ByVal lpLocalName As Long, ByVal lpRemoteName As Long, lpnLength As Long) As Long
  Private Declare Function PathIsUNC Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathIsUNCW" (ByVal pszPath As Long) As Long
  Private Declare Function PathIsNetworkPath Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathIsNetworkPathW" (ByVal pszPath As Long) As Long
  Private Declare Function PathStripToRoot Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathStripToRootW" (ByVal pPath As Long) As Long
  Private Declare Function PathSkipRoot Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathSkipRootW" (ByVal pPath As Long) As Long
  Private Declare Function PathRemoveBackslash Lib "shlwapi.dll" Alias "PathRemoveBackslashW" (ByVal strPath As Long) As Long
#End If

Public Function GetUNCPath(sLocalPath As String) As String
  Dim lResult As Long
#If VBA7 Then
  Dim lpResult As LongPtr
#Else
  Dim lpResult As Long
#End If
  Dim ASLocal As APIString
  Dim ASPath As APIString
  Dim ASRoot As APIString
  Dim ASRemoteRoot As APIString
  Dim ASTemp As APIString

  Set ASLocal = New APIString
  ASLocal.Value = sLocalPath

  If ASLocal.Pointer > 0 Then
    lResult = PathIsUNC(ASLocal.Pointer)
  End If
  If lResult <> 0 Then
    GetUNCPath = ASLocal.Value
    Exit Function
  End If

  If ASLocal.Pointer > 0 Then
    lResult = PathIsNetworkPath(ASLocal.Pointer)
  End If
  If lResult = 0 Then
    GetUNCPath = ASLocal.Value
    Exit Function
  End If

  ' Extract Root
  Set ASRoot = New APIString
  ASRoot.Value = sLocalPath
  If ASRoot.Length = 2 And Mid(ASRoot.Value, 2, 1) = ":" Then
    ' We have a Root with no Path
    Set ASPath = New APIString
    ASPath.Value = ""
  Else
    If ASRoot.Pointer > 0 Then
      lpResult = PathStripToRoot(ASRoot.Pointer)
    End If
    ASRoot.TruncToNull
    If ASRoot.Pointer > 0 And Mid(ASRoot.Value, ASRoot.Length) = "\" Then
      lpResult = PathRemoveBackslash(ASRoot.Pointer)
      ASRoot.TruncToPointer lpResult
    End If

    ' Extract Path
    Set ASPath = New APIString
    ASPath.Value = sLocalPath
    lpResult = PathSkipRoot(ASPath.Pointer)
    ASPath.TruncFromPointer lpResult
    If ASPath.Length > 0 Then
      If ASPath.Pointer > 0 And Mid(ASPath.Value, ASPath.Length) = "\" Then
        lpResult = PathRemoveBackslash(ASPath.Pointer)
        ASPath.TruncToPointer lpResult
      End If
    End If
  End If

  ' Resolve Local Root into Remote Root
  Set ASRemoteRoot = New APIString
  ASRemoteRoot.Init 255
  If ASRoot.Pointer > 0 And ASRemoteRoot.Pointer > 0 Then
    lResult = WNetGetConnection(ASRoot.Pointer, ASRemoteRoot.Pointer, LenB(ASRemoteRoot.Value))
  End If
  ASRemoteRoot.TruncToNull

  GetUNCPath = ASRemoteRoot.Value & ASPath.Value
End Function
```

**Class Module: APIString**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

 Private sBuffer As String

 Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   sBuffer = vbNullChar
 End Sub

 Private Sub Class_Terminate()
   sBuffer = ""
 End Sub

 Public Property Get Value() As String
   Value = sBuffer
 End Property

 Public Property Let Value(ByVal sNewStr As String)
   sBuffer = sNewStr
 End Property

 ' Truncates Length
#If VBA7 Then
  Public Sub TruncToPointer(ByVal lpNewUBound As LongPtr)
#Else
  Public Sub TruncToPointer(ByVal lpNewUBound As Long)
#End If
   Dim lpDiff As Long
   If lpNewUBound <= StrPtr(sBuffer) Then Exit Sub
   lpDiff = (lpNewUBound - StrPtr(sBuffer)) \ 2
   sBuffer = Mid(sBuffer, 1, lpDiff)
 End Sub

 ' Shifts Starting Point forward
#If VBA7 Then
 Public Sub TruncFromPointer(ByVal lpNewLBound As LongPtr)
#Else
 Public Sub TruncFromPointer(ByVal lpNewLBound As Long)
#End If
   Dim lDiff As Long
   If lpNewLBound <= StrPtr(sBuffer) Then Exit Sub
   If lpNewLBound >= (StrPtr(sBuffer) + LenB(sBuffer)) Then
     sBuffer = ""
     Exit Sub
   End If
   lDiff = (lpNewLBound - StrPtr(sBuffer)) \ 2
   sBuffer = Mid(sBuffer, lDiff)
 End Sub

 Public Sub Init(Size As Long)
   sBuffer = String(Size, vbNullChar)
 End Sub

Public Sub TruncToNull()
  Dim lPos As Long
  lPos = InStr(sBuffer, vbNullChar)
  If lPos = 0 Then Exit Sub
  sBuffer = Mid(sBuffer, 1, lPos - 1)
End Sub

Public Property Get Length() As Long
  Length = Len(sBuffer)
End Property

#If VBA7 Then
 Public Property Get Pointer() As LongPtr
#Else
 Public Property Get Pointer() As Long
#End If
   Pointer = StrPtr(sBuffer)
 End Property
```

Thanks for the assistance.